# remove from cart button not working, in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to hit the remove button and for my html quantity to update to one quantity lower for that item only, then remove it entirely when the quantity in 0.but when i hit the remove button nothing happens. any help is appreciated. Also my commented out foreach loop works at changing the html but changes the quantity for all products when i hit the remove button

View Below

```ts
    import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
    import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-cart',
      templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
    })
    export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    
      //added
      cartCount!: number;
    
      products: {
        product: Product,
        quantity: number,
    
      }[] = [];
      totalPrice!: number;
      cartProducts: Product[] = [];
    
      //added
      @Input() productInfo!: Product;
    
      constructor(private productService: ProductService, private router: Router) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.productService.getCart().subscribe(
          (cart) => {
            this.products = cart.products;
            this.products.forEach(
              (element) => this.cartProducts.push(element.product)
            );
            this.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice;
          }
        );
      }
    
      emptyCart(): void {
        let cart = {
          cartCount: 0,
          products: [],
          totalPrice: 0.00
        };
        this.productService.setCart(cart);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
    
      //added
      removeFromCart(product: Product): void {
    
        /*this.products.forEach(
          (element) => {
            --element.quantity;
            if(element.quantity<1){
              this.products.pop();
            }
          }
        );*/
        --product.quantity;
        if(product.quantity<1){
          this.products = this.products.filter(({product: p}) => p.id !== product.id)
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="cart-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="cart-table-body">
            <tr *ngFor="let product of products;">
                <td>{{product.product.id}}</td>
                <td>{{product.product.name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{product.product.description}}</td>
              //added
              <td><button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="removeFromCart(productInfo)">Remove from Cart</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" [routerLink]="['/home']">Back</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="emptyCart()">Empty Cart</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/checkout']">Proceed to Checkout (${{totalPrice}})</button>
```

[picture of my html][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3W3I.png

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you have `ProductInfo` as an `@Input` into the component... any particular reason I'm missing? Is this like a cart *detail* page, where you already have items in a list, and you simply click on an item in that list or table and it takes you to this page? Why not just be able to delete any item on this page?

Comment: honestly not sure. this was on my addToCart method so when trying to create this removeFromCart method i was reverse engineering it. i linked a picture at the bottom of my html page. yeah i want to just be able to delete on this page. what exactly does ProductInfo do?

Comment: Can you put this project in a github repo so that I can check it out?

Comment: yes https://github.com/RevSwagBag/SwagBag/tree/Abraham-Rantisi_Remove_Items

Comment: Sweet! I'll check it out for ya

Comment: thank you so much, wait let me push my latest updates real quick

Comment: so it kinda works except the first time a hit remove it resets the quantity to the product stock quantity, not the cart product quantity

Comment: I gotcha my man. I'll push up some changes here pretty quick and you can see kinda what i'm doing!

Comment: Pushed up some changes! checkout the PR. https://github.com/RevSwagBag/SwagBag/pull/1

Also, I put some instructions in the PR body

Comment: yeah i added u on discord, im going to look at your changes first then if needed we can hop into a call or chat. ty so much again

Answer (score 0):

`this.products.filter(({product: p}) => p.id !== product.id)`
should be
`this.products.filter((p:Product) => p.id !== product.id)`

You have the type `Product` and variable `p` switched up in your filter function.

Comment: on this product "filter((p:product)"

TS2749: 'product' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof product'?

i get this error

Comment: product with capital P like in your type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).